# Unable to change the screen brightness after installation of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: grub2, brightness

My system configurations are: Lenevo IdeaPad gaming with AMD Ryzen 5000 series, Nvidia GeForce GTX. I have referred to one of the articles and updated the grub configuration mentioned below.

Default grub configuration:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Update with the below one:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_DISALBE_OS_PROBER=”false”
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=video"
```

I am still unable to change the brightness level after this attempt.